# Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 Delta

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, product, database, category

We are doing a migration from **Magento 1** to **Magento 2**.

Step 1 and step 2 are going good, all products and settings are migrated to Magento 2. But when I do step 3 delta, only changes in products are updated, when I add a new product to Magento 1 it **does not** upgrade Magento 2 with the new product.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a feature that's not supported?

```
1 bin/magento migrate:settings
2 bin/magento migrate:data
3 bin/magento migrate:delta
```

Comment: may be try --reset? please take backup of db before.

Comment: I have already tried that without result

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to migrate **Magento-1** to **Magento-2**, before migrating please take **back-up of your data**.

After that run the following commands:

> bin/magento migrate:settings
>
> bin/magento migrate:data
>
> bin/magento migrate:delta
>
> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> chmod -R 777 var
>
> chmod -R 777 generated
>
> chmod -R 777 pub/static

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You absolutely do not want to grant write access to executable or system files to all users under any circumstances. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and learn about the Unix permissions model before you try to use it again. If this happened on a system with Internet access, check whether an intruder could have exploited this to escalate their privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool via Composer, ensuring the versions match.

Configure the Data Migration Tool by editing the `config.xml` file with the appropriate database and encryption key information.

Migrate settings using the Data Migration Tool by running

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset <path to config.xml>
```

Migrate data using the Data Migration Tool by running

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset <path to config.xml>
```

After completing these steps, you should receive a success message indicating the migration was successful.